# Trying to control

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, neopixel

I have a raspberry pi 3 model B and a Kano LED light ring

my kid stopped using the raspberry pi and i repurposed it to make a pihole, it doesn't have the KanoOS anymore and just has the regular raspbian OS running my DNS server.

The lights on the LED were always on really bright (white only), and I wanted to learn how to change the colors. I used the code below, which when I ran the program it turned the lights off but won't turn them back on. If I restart the pi, it will turn them back on. If I rerun the code it turns them all off again. Anyone have any ideas on how to trouble shoot this?

```
import board
import neopixel

pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D18, 10, brightness=0.3, auto_write=False)
pixels[0] = (255, 0 , 0)
pixels.show()
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Excuse me to say sth unrelated a bit but you can use [wokwi](https://wokwi.com/) to simulate your run and make sure if the error was from the code or the raspberry pi

Comment: Thank you so much! That is a cool tool and it's going to help me learn (which is my end goal).